# Chrome doesn't do anything when trying to update

Tags: windows, windows-8, google-chrome, windows-8.1, updates

My Chrome bar has been nagging at me for a week now, wanting me to update to the latest version of Chrome. If I click the hotdog menu (or is it hamburger menu?) and hit the Update Google Chrome button, then click Relaunch, all it does is close the current window. My little Hangouts bubbles I have on the desktop don't go away, and Chrome never actually starts up again, and when I click on the icon again, unsurprisingly it still wants me to update it.

Quitting Chrome from the Task Manager seems to be the only working method. Why doesn't the regular update button work?

Comment: If you download the Chrome installer does Chrome update properly?

Comment: This might https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/tdlOv4V4jDk%5B1-25%5D help you have a look at this.

Answer (score 0):

It would appear you have background working in play  when running  select the chrome panel icon  uncheck let chrome background then relaunch